# center div in flex div while mantaining aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to keep the box 'c' in the middle of 'a' and with padding 30px 10px 10px 10px, so that it has a bit more room at the top and equal room from the other sides. but I want box 'c' to not only be in between those bounds but also centered vertically and horizontally within 'a' and when you make box 'b' width larger than it shrinks 'a' and 'c' mantaining c's aspect ratio, the same for making 'b' width smaller and stopping 'c' from growing further than its limits and preventing it from overflowing. Also 'b' width/height will grow only until it reaches 200px.

This is the template and my attempt in css:

```
<div class='z'>
<div class='a'>
    <div class='c'></div>
</div>
<div class='b'>
</div>
```

```
.z {
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.a {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 30px 10px 10px 10px;
    flex: 1;
}

.b {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 200px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.c {
    background-color: red;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

This is my attempt in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c8w79mLx/

Answer (score 0):

in this what you are looking for?  [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c8w79mLx/1/)

Insteed of using padding to the "a" box I used absolute positioning to the c box:

```
.c {
    background-color: red;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;top:30px;right:10px;left:10px;
}
```

Comment: no, i want the red box to be centered at all time, and when stretched it must mantain it's aspect ratio width = height. and also it should not overflow when the yellow box's width is too little.

Answer (score 0):

changed the css for the a class to:

```
.a {
background-color: blue;
flex: 1;
padding: 50px 10px;
align-items: center;
```

}

and for the c class to:

```
.c {
background-color: red;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

}

fiddle update here --> http://jsfiddle.net/c8w79mLx/6/